# How to open a image in Photoshop using Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, photoshop

I wanted to open a local image file in Photoshop using flex.
How I can achieve this. Is there any libraries which is used to run Photoshop and open specified image using actionScript?

Comment: AIR or web app? Can't do it from web app for security reasons.

Comment: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Open_file_with_Default_Application_AIR_2_0-16745.html

Comment: OK. can we specify open with Photoshop through script rather than setting it as default application for image types.

Comment: Not sure. Haven't tried yet. But with nativeProcess you should be able to do anything.